# Difference in typing when passing spread props vs html-style attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript

## Summary:

Typescript gives an error when passing a prop through standard `propName={propValue}` but not when using spread props `{...{propName: propValue}}`

To clarify: *I know how to solve this*. I could add it explicitly to the `IconButtonProps` type; I could also add `& React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>` so I don't have to iterate all button props that I want to be able to pass through; I could also just use spread props everywhere (which is what I do 90% of the time anyway).

However, it seems like these two components should be the same. **I'm looking to understand why these two supposedly equivalent ways of passing props behave differently in typescript.**

## Code Example

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=32&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AoGATzCTgEk0IA7AIQFcYYWAFHMAM5wAvHADe5OHDQAbFAIEA5FCCQB+AFxwBMKMGYBzClPwo9KALRyARkhn4tOvYYoBfCuSbMdDLxy4sInAAFGLScgrKqgA0cAB0CRAwABZIUHwQgnCuWows-tzMGYIAlCIAfOKScEQw7FDMIdVSADzWnIXiCXFJqen8Aq7h8koqSMJisiNRSK7lzVJwYLVIzAAmDHAqW43AXgstAPTtAczzUiVuHl4+AMK4kMyrMADqwCkAglx6J0hCosEysJKhIpDd4MkUOsZEhbjI9gBrIKAipVRbSFgCCAwuIyCAGYL4KgQEn4S7Vdzkaq1eqNFp5NgdQJmYCWGx2YT4EBQlAGOgCJAYYAsfBwFhwxETSHQ2HwtAIoaHcpXKnguD3cAsZ5vFIAZWWqDWxX+ISBIOqaulaxhEvlyLNaMWN2xSFx+MJxNJ5KklOpSDqDSa6PpfiZjRZbJQthknO5zF5-MFMGFzFFYm6YXFcoRWitNuz2UV5zg5MpQA)

```
import React from "react";

type IconButtonProps = {
  className?: string;
  "aria-label": string;
};

const IconButton = ({ className, ...otherProps }: IconButtonProps) => {
  return (
    <button {...otherProps} className={className}>
      pretend I am an icon
    </button>
  );
};

const ComponentWithAttributes = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("yooo");
  };

  return <IconButton aria-label="manage section" onClick={handleClick} />;
};

const ComponentWithSpreadProps = () => {
  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("yooo");
  };

  return (
    <IconButton aria-label="manage section" {...{ onClick: handleClick }} />
  );
};
```

`ComponentWithAttributes` gives this error:

```
Type '{ "aria-label": string; onClick: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconButtonProps'.
  Property 'onClick' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IconButtonProps'.(2322)
```

`ComponentWithSpreadProps` has no errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [structural typing](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) nature of typescript. You can read more in the link provided.

When you spread an object, you don't ***really*** know its properties, or if it has excess properties, as some objects properties are inherited. Typescript does not catch errors on any other properties on the spread object.

example

```
var x = { d: 0 };
var y: { a: number, b: string } = {
    a: 0,
    b: "",
    ...x,
    d: 100
};
```

Typescripts will raise an error when you try to assign `d` in `y`, but will allow spreading of `x`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand that typescript uses structural typing, however I don't understand why these two supposedly equivalent ways of passing props would end up with different types

Comment: @augzodia i modified my ans with more description of the problem, which is the reason for typescript allowing other properties for spread.

Comment: The edit is very helpful! I went back and played with the example and saw that I could pass in an `onClick` with the wrong signature and typescript didn't care about that either. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the missing "onClick" in your IconButtonProps type.

I just edit to:

```
type IconButtonProps = { className?: string; "aria-label": string; onClick: () => void };
```

and the error is gone

Regards!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I should have added that I know I can add the prop to the types, but I don't understand why the two components should behave differently